# Computer restarts with OpenGL and Catalyst newer than 11.7

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, amd-radeon, opengl

You guys are my last hope literally, before I have to replace my motherboard/CPU/RAM and Graphics Card.

When I start OpenGL Programs in full screen and the same resolution as my desktop, my computer reboots. It is not a Windows shutdown, it just reboots instantly. It also happens sometimes when Windows asks for admin rights. But with OpenGL Programs, this is reproducible. Also happens with programs I write myself or with games. Does not matter.

This happens only with Catalyst 11.8 or newer. It does not happen with 11.7.

I already replaced my PSU with a Corsair TX650V2, because many people told me that this may cause the issue. But obviously it didn't. I replaced my old, really crummy PSU with the new one and still have the error. I am sticking with the 11.7 drivers for now, but it bugs me. Maybe something is broken and my PC about to die.

Memtest completed without errors.

- motherboard: GIGABYTE ga-ma78gm-s2h
- RAM: Corsair 4x 2GB DDR2
- hard drive: 80GB SATA Matrox
- Graphics: Sapphire Radeon HD4890 1GB GDDR5
- CPU: AMD ATHLON 5600+ X2, 2.7ghz per core

Comment: Have you disabled Restart on System Failure? http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/automatic-restart-windows-7.htm

Comment: Yes, of course. And there is no event entry.